# Extracting information part of log file and inserting into Oracle

Tags: shell

I have a log file that looks like this:

```
File: /ora/backups/DBNAME1/ Export: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on 
File: /ora/backups/DBNAME2/ Export: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on 
File: /ora/backups/DBNAME3/ Export: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on 
File: /ora/backups/DBNAME4/ Export: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on 
File: /ora/backups/DBNAME5/ Export: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on 
File: /ora/backups/DBNAME6/ Export: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on
```

I need to write a script to get the `DBNAME` and Version from this file and insert into Oracle.

I have written the following code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
log_file=/ora/backups/backups.log ; export log_file

###  I have setup Oracle Environment here

      db_name=$(grep Export: $log_file | cut -d '/' -f4)
      db_ver=$(grep Export: $log_file | cut -d ' ' -f5)
      echo $db_name
      echo $db_ver
```

The above code gives me the output, but I need to know how to create an iteration to insert every `db_name` and `db_ver` in a single row of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[ -f query01.sql ] && : > query01.sql
while IFS= read -r line
do 
  db_name=$(echo "${line}" | grep 'Export:' | cut -d '/' -f4); 
  db_ver=$(echo "${line}" | grep 'Export:' | cut -d ' ' -f5); 
  echo "insert into your_tab_name values (${db_name},${db_ver});" >> query01.sql
done < ${log_file}
```

Replace `your_tab_name` with the applicable table name. You can use this `query01.sql` in your DB calling block of statements.

**Example**

Output of `query01.sql`:

```
insert into tab_name_this values (DBNAME1,11.2.0.3.0);
insert into tab_name_this values (DBNAME2,11.2.0.3.0);
insert into tab_name_this values (DBNAME3,11.2.0.3.0);
insert into tab_name_this values (DBNAME4,11.2.0.3.0);
insert into tab_name_this values (DBNAME5,12.1.0.2.0);
insert into tab_name_this values (DBNAME6,12.2.0.1.0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked with a little bit tweaking for my environment.